# What does an assignment expression evaluate to in Java?

Tags: java, expression, file-handling, assignment-operator

I encountered a statement in Java

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.append(line);
}
```

How do assignment operations return a value in Java?

The statement we are checking is `line = reader.readLine()` and we compare it with `null`.

Since `readLine` will return a string, how exactly are we checking for `null`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The assignment operator in Java evaluates to the assigned value (like it does in, e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)). So here, `readLine()` will be executed, and its return value stored in `line`. That stored value is then checked against `null`, and if it's `null` then the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 11):

> (line = reader.readLine()) != null

means

1. the method readLine() is invoked.
2. the result is assigned to variable **line**,
3. the new value of **line** will be proof against **null**

maybe many operations at once...

Answer (score 9):

Assignment expressions are evaluated to their assignment value.

```
(test = read.readLine())
```

>>

```
(test = <<return value>>)
```

>>

```
<<return value>>
```

Comment: my question is do expressions also return something as according to you at that time 
(line=null), will that mean it will again return null back?

Comment: @sunder  I edited my answer to address your question about the evaluation of assignment expressions.

Answer (score 8):

[The Java® Language Specification 15.26. Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

`reader.readLine()` reads and returns a line for you. Here, you assigned whatever returned from that to line and check if the line variable is null or not.