# confused with return value of assignment operation in java

Tags: java

I tried to understand how exactly the return value of assignment operation works.
followed by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163938/return-value-of-assignment-operation-in-java) "Java returns the assigned value".

```
    boolean b1 = false, b2 = false;
    if (b2 = b1 == false) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

b2 is true because of `(b1 == false)` return true, then the return of b2 assignment `b2 = true`

Or is it because of some other reason?

Comment: its the game of `precedence` of `assignment` and `equal to`. @Pau

Comment: See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it right. The [operator precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) make sure that first the `==` operator is evaluated. That's `b1==false`, yielding true. After that, the assigned is executed, setting `b2` to true. Finally, the assignment operator returns the value as b2, which is evaluated by the `if` statement.

Comment: `int i = doIt() / (j = 2);` , why the method execution comes before the grouping & accessing operators ?  they are in the top level of [Operator Precedence and Parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/176/operators/9207/operator-precedence-and-parentheses#t=201701111907181800707) .thanks

Comment: Java usually evaluates the terms from the left to the right (pretty much like we humans do, at least in the western hemisphere). So we start with `doIt`. Next thing we see is a `()`. That's top priority, so we call the function. After that we encounter the `/`, priority 13. It's followed by another `(`, priority 16. So we evaluate `j=2` first. Having done that, we return to the division. That happens to be the last step in the evaluation.

Comment: Another possible explanation is that `doIt()` is a singular term. In Java, you can't do anything with the name of a method. Other programming languages may treat it as an useful entity of its own (function pointers, lambda expression etc.). Java doesn't do such a thing. If it finds a method name in an expression, the only sensible thing to do is to execute it. From this point of view, `doIt` and `()` belong together and can't be separated. They are a single, atomar term of the expression. Little wonder the method is evaluated first, no matter what comes next.