# Setting a variable in a return statement

Tags: java, return

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ufOPX8N1Rg), I saw that the programmer used a return statement of this form in a static method:

```
public static int staticFunc(int x, int y) {
    return x = y;
}
```

*(This is not the exact function, which can be found at [10:11](https://youtu.be/5ufOPX8N1Rg?t=10m11s) in the video)*

Why is this (assigning a variable in a return statement) used instead of simply returning x? And what is the name of this type of statement?

*additional context:
the video is about making games in java, and the method in the video is specified in the game object to allow a player object to only move in the bounds of the window. This function is used to update a property in the player object.*

Comment: Disclaimer: I understand that it is very likely a question like this has been asked before, however it does not show up in the ways that I am looking for it, so hopefully we can route this to an existing answer

Comment: This just returns y. It is a silly example.

Comment: `int x` is a call-by-value argument. So assigning it before the return has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good reason I can think of to write it that way, especially since Java is call-by-value, i.e. assigning an input to something new inside the body of a function won't change that variable outside the scope of the function.

It makes me think the person in that video just has a poor understanding of that fact.

In other contexts, the result of an assignment expression is the value that is assigned to the variable, so you can do things like

```
String someName = "Tom";
System.out.println(someName = "John");
```

and it will print John to the console, as well as assign "John" to `someName`.

But in the context of your function, there's no good reason to do it the way presented in the video.

Answer (score 0):

> ....[W]hat is the name of this type of statement?

"Silly", "frustrating", "amateurish", or my personal favorite: "unnecessary".

There's no reason to do what the author of the code is doing there.  The only thing that will happen is that you will be returning `y`, which raises the question of why the method exists in the first place.

There *are* valid cases in which you would want to use an assignment operator in a specific context - namely, [if you wanted to use a throwaway variable to process something for you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163938/1079354), but in this context, there's *nothing* being gained from this except a lot of confusion for anyone else reading the code.

While I can't speak to the video, I'd recommend - if you need a statement like this - to use a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) instead to do your transformation, if it's necessary at all.