# Finding the sum of numbers in a row without an array

Tags: java

I wrote this program that prints a table that shows the powers of x, now i have to modify it so that it prints the sum of each row, after each row and i have no idea where to really start.  i thought about putting the numbers into an array and adding them like that but that seems like its way too overly complicated.

```
public class table {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final int NMAX = 5;
    final double XMAX = 10;

    for(int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++) 
    {
        System.out.printf("%10d", n);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%10s", "x ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(double x = 1; x <= XMAX; x++)
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%10.0f", Math.pow(x, n));
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does putting them into an array work?

Comment: A different, refactoring suggestion -- always separate calculations from presentation.

Comment: i want to use an int variable for summation, i can add them and put the sums at the end of the program but i need to make an extra column on the end that has the sums of each row from top to bottom.  i think i need to change something inside the last loop that makes it print an extra column with all the sums im just not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please format (indent) code correctly.

Comment: You build one row at a time, and you just need a single `sum` value, so why would you need an array? Set `sum = 0` before the loop printing row values, add value to `sum` as you print them, then print sum after loop before the `println()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey i think that i understand you. Here is the code i made some changes but nothing too complex for understanding. If you have some questions feel free to ask.

```
    final int NMAX = 6;
    final double XMAX = 10;

    for(int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%10d", n);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%10s", "x ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    int counter = 0;
    for(double x = 1; x <= XMAX; x++)
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= NMAX; n++)
        {
            if(n == 6){
                System.out.printf("%10d",counter);
                counter = 0;
            }else{
                System.out.printf("%10.0f", Math.pow(x, n));
                counter += Math.pow(x, n);

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @Steve i have edited the printing stuff so now it is working perfect. Do you understand what i did in the code?

Comment: I get what this code is supposed to do but its not working for me and i cant figure out why, i used 5 instead of 6 because the original value was actually supposed to be 4 but i just get a blank column at the end labelled 5 and i cant figure out why it isnt printing the values.

Comment: oh wait a minute i didnt see the edit before i posted that comment

Comment: oh that %10d was why it wasnt printing right, thanks alot my program works now.

Comment: @Steve Am i didnt edit too much just this line System.out.printf("%10d",counter);  instead of   System.out.printf(" 
        ",counter);

Comment: @Steve I am glad to hear that, if you find answer as useful just mark the answer as helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve what you want changing the last part of your program like this (if NMAX is always the number of columns):

```java
double pow, sum;
for(double x = 1; x <= XMAX; x++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int n = 1; n < NMAX; n++)
        {
            sum += (pow = Math.pow(x, n));
            System.out.printf("%10.0f", pow);
        }
        System.out.printf("%10.0f", sum);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This line may be confusing:

```
sum += (pow = Math.pow(x, n));
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163938/return-value-of-assignment-operation-in-java), the assignment operator returns the assigned value. In this case, we're assigning the result from `Math.pow(x, n)` to the variable `pow` and then add that same value to the variable `sum`.

This way you only call `Math.pow` once, since you're saving the value in a variable to print it later.

Doing it this way allows you to change the variable `NMAX` to any value without needing to change anything else in your program.