# Is it possible to concatenate assignments in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, variable-assignment

Is it possible to assign to two variables in one statement?

E.g.

```
this.edge = this.side = null;
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163938/return-value-of-assignment-operation-in-java

Comment: I just tried, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Adding one line will not cost you much, just use:

```
this.edge = null;
this.side = null;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: No, @JessedeBruijne, but it gives good *and relevant* guidance pertaining to the question asked.

Comment: @OleV.V. True, but then it's probably better as a comment.