# Single equal in different situation

Tags: java, equality

I have this code...

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean mySuperBoolean = Boolean.FALSE;

        System.out.print("a");
        if (mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE) {
            System.out.print("b");
        }

        System.out.print("c");
    }
}
```

I am new to Java, but I knew single equal (=) is used to assign. And double equals (==) is used to check if object is referred to the same location in memory. However, in this case I do not understand how the 'b' is being printed with a single equals, but I understand changing it to a double equals sign will not print it out

Comment: `==` not `=` in the if

Comment: `mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE` should be `mySuperBoolean == Boolean.TRUE`,

Comment: This is because `mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE` returns true

Comment: [Using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html)

Comment: Somehow related: [Return value of assignment operation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163938/return-value-of-assignment-operation-in-java)

Comment: I have voted to reopen since this question is not about a simple error and its correction, but about *understanding* how it can be that the version with single `=` behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE)` will **assign** Boolean.TRUE to your `mySuperBoolean` variable and the condition will evaluate to true, hence whatever is inside your if it will always execute

Answer (score 2):

Assignment is an [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) which resolves to whatever was assigned, in this case
`(mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE)` is an expression which resolves to `Boolean.TRUE`.

This is really only useful in a few specific situations. One such case is the following idiom:

```
String line;
while ((line = readLine()) != null) {
    //...
}
```

Or even

```
i = j = k = 0; // equal to: i = (j = (k = 0))
```

It's a controversial feature because it allows *probable* bugs such as yours to compile successfully. To mitigate this, some people will invert the operands (a ["yoda condition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)):

```
if (Boolean.TRUE == mySuperBoolean)
```

This works because if I forget the second equals then the compiler will throw an error because `Boolean.TRUE` is final and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: This is the well explained answer, thank you. I don’t hink I ever use the value of an assignment for anything, your example is idiomatic, though. The other example goes like `i = j = k = 0;`, which sets al of `i`, `j` and `k` to 0. Instead of `if (mySuperBoolean == Boolean.TRUE)` I strongly recommend just `if (mySuperBoolean)`, it also evades the issue of the forgotten extra equals sign.

Comment: `if (mySuperBoolean)` is not always possible, if `mySuperBoolean` were a nullable Boolean.

Comment: Good point, @Michael. However, that’s subtle, there’s something dangerous about nullable `Boolean` as a whole. But if you insist, make the null check explicit: `if (mySuperBoolean != null && mySuperBoolean)`. Would be my recommendation. The intention and everything is clearer than in the Yoda condition case.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the assignment operator `=` will be the assigned value. So `if (mySuperBoolean = Boolean.TRUE)` will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, what happens here boils down to:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE) {
  System.out.print("b");
}
```

That assignment puts TRUE into the variable, the variable is boolean, and checked for its current value, end of story.